# App works fine in simulator but throws NSUnknownKeyException exception on device

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin

I am trying to create a simple Hello World test application in Xamarin Studio. I create a blank Single View iPhone application without Story Board.

I drag & drop an ImageView on the View and connect an outlet for it. Just simple as this.

When I run in the simulator it works fine but it throws NSUnknownKeyException while debugging on the device.

I checked the usual suspects:

1. Check undefined outlets with an exclamation mark
2. Checked the designer.cs file
3. Check .h and .m files
4. Clean & rebuild all
5. Clear the Main Interface setting from the Deployment Options
6. Set the Custom Class definition
7. Compile with -f option
8. Update to latest Xcode, Monotouch & Xamarin Studio (Xamarin Studio 4.2.3, Xcode 5.1, 7.2.0.2 (Starter Edition)
9. Updated the iPhone 5s to IOS 7.1

I still get the same exception. Below are the codes and the error info. Am I missing a very obvious thing here or somehow the sync between Xcode and Xamarin Studio fails?

I appreciate any help.

Error log

> MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.
>   Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key imgTest.   at at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend
>   (intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible ()
>   [0x00008] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/build/compat/UIKit/.pmcs-compat.UIWindow.g.cs:130
>   at TestProject.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching
>   (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary
>   options) [0x00038] in
>   /Users/gorken/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/AppDelegate.cs:31   at
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String
>   delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pmcs-compat.UIApplication.cs:38
>   at TestProject.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in
>   /Users/gorken/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/Main.cs:16

TestProjectViewController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class TestProjectViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public TestProjectViewController () : base ("TestProjectViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
    }
}
```

TestProjectViewController.designer.cs

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace TestProject
{
    [Register ("TestProjectViewController")]
    partial class TestProjectViewController
    {
        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImageView imgTest { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (imgTest != null) {
                imgTest.Dispose ();
                imgTest = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace TestProject
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;
        TestProjectViewController viewController;
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            viewController = new TestProjectViewController ();
            window.RootViewController = viewController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

TestProjectViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TestProjectViewController : UIViewController {
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgTest;

@end
```

TestProjectViewController.m

```
#import "TestProjectViewController.h"

@implementation TestProjectViewController

- (void)dealloc {
    [_imgTest release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

The xib file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="5053" systemVersion="13C64" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3733"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="TestProjectViewController">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="imgTest" destination="PLQ-yP-dMH" id="f4J-3q-Qoq"/>
                <outlet property="view" destination="6" id="7"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="6">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" id="PLQ-yP-dMH">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                </imageView>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.75" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google, I found that cleaning and rebuilding your solution helps clear this error (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15002).
To clean and rebuild your solution, in Xamarin studio, go to "build" on the top of your screen, and click "Clean All". After that, click "Rebuild All".

If this doesn't work for you, have a look at your info.plist in the "Main Interface" settings. An error there might throw this exception.

Another reason for this exception might be when an outlet exists for a control that no longer exists in Interface Builder. Check the designer files again (maybe use Xcode to do an extra check if everything is a-okay).

Let me know if this helps you. Good luck!

Love and regards,
Björn